# angularjs app not working after code concatination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller

I have and angularjs app.I want to concatenate all the **JS** files to a single file.I'm currently trying to use Grunt.js to setup an automatic build process for concatenating JavaScript files.

However my app runs without any error before concatenation.But after concatinating the files my app throws **Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error**.

Below is my code after minification

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);


var app = angular
  .module('myApp', [ 
    'ngRoute'
  ]);

 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCntrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCntrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

   app.controller('mainCntrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
   'use strict';

    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    
  }]);

app.controller('aboutCntrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

Any help appreciated.Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to strictly follow either `Inline Array Annotation` of DI or `$inject Property Annotation` while minifying js files.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    //code 
});
```

should be changed to below code.

[**Inline Array Annotation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    //code as is
}]);
```

[**`$inject` Property Annotation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation)

```
var config = function($routeProvider) {
   'use strict';
   //code as is
}
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
app.config(config);
```

Comment: I added **$routeProvide** as DI.But still it doesnt seem to work.app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)

Comment: @dennyjohn do verify other files too, you must be missing same thing somewhere else?

Comment: these are the only files I have.This app works fine when the code is not concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the config line is your problem, try `app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) { ... }]);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your annotation is not right. It should be

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    //code
}]);
```

Use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) as a safe, clean and simple solution.

What it does is that when you `grunt` it'll annotate your definitions the proper way, so you don't have to deal with Angular's quirky way.

Run ng-annotate on

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  'use strict';
  //code 
});
```

and it'll auto-complete it for minification:

```
app.config(["routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  'use strict';
  //code 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add another step to your build workflow - [grunt-ng-annotate](https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate) in that case you will be able to skip almost all strict DI annotations. With this plugin you can simplify services/controllers definitions e.g.:

```
app.controller('mainCntrl', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

It is extremely helpful when you heave a long list of services to inject into controller or another service. You don't have to remember to put each dependency twice.